# AWS Route53: Get DNS record set creation time

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I use Python SDK to delete DNS record sets in `Route53`. Due to `Route53` API throttling, the deletion fails sometimes and the stale DNS record set is building up.

As the DNS record set approaches the 10,000 limit, I want to delete the record sets that were created last year because they are not needed any longer. But I am unable to find the record creation time either using `AWS CLI` or using Python SDK (`Boto3`). Is there a way to get the DNS record creation time in `Route53` using `CLI` or `SDK`?

Comment: I'm not seeing any indication that Amazon even tracks the record creation time of Route53 DNS record sets, are you? You might be stuck doing something like querying all your CloudTrail logs with Athena for the last time each record was updated.

Comment: I was about to suggest CloudTrail. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html#cloudtrail-understanding-route-53-entries

Comment: @MarkB and Rodrigo - yes CloudTrail is an option but I was looking for a SDK/CLI solution. Looks like AWS doesn't store this information. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand from documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/get-change.html)
`aws r53` stores timestamp of `change-resource-record-sets` request, but you need to know request id: `aws route53 get-change --id /change/<request_id>`

Answer (score 2):

After analysing the root cause of the problem you are facing, I think it is not specifically related to python or boto3, but it is related to your algorithm and aws route 53 service behavior, you said:

> I use Python SDK to delete DNS record sets in Route53. Due to Route53
>   API throttling, the deletion fails sometimes and the stale DNS record
>   set is building up.

I would recommend you to use a SQS queue as intermediate to delete records from Route53 asynchronously, eventually using [exponential backoff](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/exponential-backoff-and-jitter/) and [dead letter queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) to improve the reliability of your process if you think some deletion is broken by another reason and should be postponed.

Comment: If you think this would be the way to go, I think you should change the question from "AWS Route53: Get DNS record set creation time" to "how to reliably delete DNS recordset from a route 53  hosted zone"